# How to take complete backup of salesforce org using VS Code

Tags: vs-code, backup

I am using VS code And installed below two packages

1. Salesforce CLI Integration (https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli)
2. Salesforce extension

And Want to take complete backup of org, when I Check in my package.xml file which is in manifest folder it has only limited components like apex triggers, apex classes etc, But i want to include all the components or members like email templates, static resource everythhing. As I want to take complete back up of org.

how do I include them in package.xml other than adding manually eac of them in file. Is any other way doing it ?

Sorry for the simple question, I'm new to VS Code and learning my way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all the metadata types to your package XML. If you don't want to do it by hand, You can use this VS Code extension which is similar to the UX in Mavens

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VignaeshRamA.sfdx-package-xml-generator